# print value of content inside div class for Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website for a college project. The website is: https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9

I want to get the ratings provided by every user for the product, the ratings are not in the text format and are present as below. I want the value 4 to be extracted from the content.

I have tried several ways to do it. But getting an error every time and the correct data can not be retrieved:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

stars_comb=[]

req = Request('https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

ratings = soup.find_all('div', class_='avg-stars')
print(ratings)
```

Kindly anybody please help me, I am new to programming and python.

Comment: the value 4? Can you give some context? I have no idea what the "4" is in reference to

Comment: That's what I was assuming as well. But just wanted clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through all the 10 pages of reviews and ignore the 10 other product reviews at the bottom of each page that also use the `avg-stars` class, try something like this that first isolates only the reviews for the Samsung Galaxy S9 Phone before searching for the `avg-stars` class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main():
  all_review_stars = []
  base_url = 'https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9?review_page='
  last_page_num = 10
  for page_num in range(1, last_page_num + 1):
    page_link = base_url + str(page_num)
    page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=5)
    page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
    reviews_stars_for_page = page_content.find_all("div", class_="review-item-stars")
    for review_stars in reviews_stars_for_page:
      all_review_stars.append(review_stars.find("div", class_="avg-stars")['data-stars'])
    print(f"Got stars for page {page_num}")
  print(f"Retrived the stars given from {len(all_review_stars)} reviews")
  all_review_stars = list(map(int, all_review_stars))
  print(all_review_stars)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
Got stars for page 1
Got stars for page 2
Got stars for page 3
Got stars for page 4
Got stars for page 5
Got stars for page 6
Got stars for page 7
Got stars for page 8
Got stars for page 9
Got stars for page 10
Retrived the stars given from 94 reviews
[5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ratings = soup.find_all('div', class_='avg-stars')     
for rating in ratings:
            print(rating.get('data-stars'))
```

#### output:

```
4.6063829787234
4.6063829787234
5
5
...
```

---

#### Updated:

If customer reviews from all pages:

```
import math
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = Request('https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
total_review = soup.find('div', class_='product-highlights-results').get('data-reviews-count')
per_page_review_limit = 10
total_pages = math.ceil( int(total_review ) / per_page_review_limit )

for (page in range(1, toatl_pages+1)):
     req = Request('https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9?review_page={}'.format(page), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
     webpage = urlopen(req).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
     print('stars from review_page: {}'.format(page))
     for star in soup.find_all('div', class_='review-item-stars'):
         print(star.div['data-stars'])
```

Comment: This won't work there are other products with the class 'avg-stars' at the bottom of the page i.e. not the Samsung Galaxy S9. I.e. searching for that class will give you 20 results when there are only 10 reviews on the page.

Comment: he also is looking for all reviews

Comment: Hi,

Can anyone please check to answer the below question:
@shash678

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346802/get-text-inside-a-span-class-of-a-particular-div?noredirect=1#comment97418870_55346802

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of pages from the reviewCount in the json of one of the script tags and then loop. The following prints review text and star rating from all the pages.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import math

baseUrl = 'https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9?review_page={}'
url = 'https://www.influenster.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s9'
reviewsPerPage = 10
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    reg = re.compile(r'"reviewCount": "(\d+)"')
    data = soup.find('script', text=reg).text
    numReviews = int(reg.findall(data)[0])
    numPages = math.ceil(numReviews/reviewsPerPage)
    stars = [item['data-stars'] for item in soup.select('.review-item [data-stars]')]
    reviewText = [item.text.strip().replace('\xa0','') for item in soup.select('.review-text')]
    results = list(zip(reviewText,stars))
    print(results)

    if numPages > 1:
        for page in range(2, numPages + 1):
            r = s.get(baseUrl.format(page), headers = headers)
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            stars = [item['content'] for item in soup.select('[itemprop="ratingValue"]')]
            reviewText = [item.text.strip().replace('\xa0','') for item in soup.select('.review-text')]
            results = list(zip(reviewText,stars))
            print(results)
```

Comment: There are some encoding issues to have  a look at more closely.

Comment: Does this have all the expected info you want?

Comment: Thank You @shash678 and everybody else for your suggestions...it worked like magic