# Get text inside a span class of a particular div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am scraping the T-Mobile website for reviews on Samsung Galaxy S9. I am able to create a Beautiful Soup object for the HTML code, but I cannot fetch the text of reviews which is present inside a span class, also need to iterate through the pages of reviews to collect all the reviews.

I have tried 2 codes, but one is returning an error and the other is returning an empty list. I also cannot find the particular span class I require in the soup object.

```python
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tmo_ratings_s9 = []

req = Request('https://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone/samsung-galaxy-s9', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
tmo_soup_s9 = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
tmo_soup_s9.prettify()
for review in tmo_soup_s9.find_all(class_="BVRRReviewText"):
    text = review.span.get_text(strip=True)
    tmo_soup_s9.append(text)

print(tmo_ratings_s9)


############################################################################

from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone/samsung-galaxy-s9")

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)

ratings = soup.find_all('div', class_='BVRRReviewTextParagraph BVRRReviewTextFirstParagraph BVRRReviewTextLastParagraph')     
textofrep = ratings.get_text().strip()
tmo_ratings_s9.append(textofrep)
```

I expect to get the text of the reviews from all the 8 pages on the webpage and store them in an HTML file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. Furthermore it also helps you solving the question yourself.

Comment: [link](https://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone/samsung-galaxy-s9)

Comment: @shash678: I have no idea of selenium...is there no way that it can be scraped in python...the particular div class <span class="BVRRReviewText">Terrible **  is not even present in the soup object

Comment: @shash678: but the current code is also not working for scraping the web page reviews on page 1, what should be done for that?
I am also thinking of saving the web pages as HTML format on my local drive and then scrap it...will it be possible then?

Comment: @SukritSen have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the data due to dynamic content loading through script. You can try selenium along with scrapy.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['t-mobile.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone/samsung-galaxy-s9']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        body = str.encode(self.driver.page_source)
        self.parse_response(HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8'))

    def parse_response(self, response):
        tmo_ratings_s9 = []
        for review in response.css('#reviews div.BVRRContentReview'):
            text = review.css('.BVRRReviewText::text').get().strip()
            tmo_ratings_s9.append(text)

        print(tmo_ratings_s9)

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

first if you are using google chrome or mozilla firefox please press ctrl+u from the page, then you will go to the page source. Check if the review content is present anywhere in the source by searching some keywords. If present write the xpath of that data, if not present, check the network section for any json requests sending while the page loads, if not present you will have to use selenium.

In your case send request to this page 
https://t-mobile.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/9060redes2-en_us/E4F08F7E-8C29-4420-BE87-9226A6C0509D/reviews.djs?format=embeddedhtml

This is a json request send while loading the whole page.

Comment: @Agnus Mathew Thank You for the insights...can you please tell me how did you produce this link from the website? I want to know how to create the json request

Comment: if you are using google chrome or mozilla right click on the page and click inspect, then in the inspect tab choose network and check preserve log and reload the page, then you will see all the requests sent during the loading of the page, from there you can search for your keywords

Answer (score 0):

use selenium or webscraper.io

> https://www.webscraper.io/
>
> https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp